# I cannot really tell what is out of range

Tags: python

I keep getting this error and I don't even know what is wrong, so what happens is I get some random indexes from the array temp which holds only integers from 0 to the `len(students_grades)` after that I go to the `students_grades` and get the value of the indexes I just got and store it in the object called `cluster`-> have two attributes (centroid and individuals)

What I want to do is the following, I want to generate some random indexes from the array temp and then take those indexes and go get their values from the array `students_grades` and then I want to remove that index from `students_grades` ..can someone help?

```py
        data = pd.read_csv("CourseEvaluation.csv", header=None)
        students_grades = []
        for i in range(1, 151):
        students_grades.append([float(data.values[i, j]) for j in range(1, 21)])
    
        k = int(input("enter how many clusters :"))
        indices = numpy.random.choice(temp, k, False)
        initial_clusters = []
        for i in range(0, len(indices)):
            print("product number:", indices[i] + 1)
            cluster = Cluster(students_grades[indices[i]], 
            students_grades[indices[i]])
            students_grades.pop(indices[i])
            initial_clusters.append(cluster)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 103, in <module>
    cluster = Cluster(students_grades[indices[i]], students_grades[indices[i]])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Hard to tell since your snippet doesn't define students_grades.

Comment: What is inside the variable `students_grades`?

Comment: Just print `len(indices)` and `len(students_grade)` you'll know why

Comment: student_grades is an array of arrays and the inner arrays are holding floats

Comment: Saying they are floats does not answer the intent of the question, which was to discover *how many* floats it contains.

Comment: 3000 floats, 20 in each array

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reorganise your code a bit ;-)
Any way, I can't be a hundred percent sure, but I'm guessing your problem is the following: you're making an array of random indices, named indices, with potentially largest value temp - 1, which might occur at any point in that array (but only once):

```
indices = numpy.random.choice(temp, k, False)
```

Next you loop over those indices, and at every step you're reducing the size of your students_grades list:
`students_grades.pop(indices[i])`

So assuming that temp = len(students_grades) at the start of this, after i steps the length of students_grades is only temp - i, but the index you are getting from your indexes array can be as high as temp - 1 so you can get index out of bound errors.
To remedy this, remember that

```
indices = numpy.random.choice(temp, k, False)
```

means that you won't get the same index twice, so it isn't necessary to remove the value at the index from students_grades.

BTW just some general python style advise: instead of

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    stuff with some_list[i]
```

you can use

```
for element in some_list:
    stuff with element
```

for more readable, 'pythonic', code ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the advice 
but the thing is:
`indices = numpy.random.choice(temp, k, False)`
is only called in the for loop which loops from 0 to `len(indices)` which is basically `k` and there is no way `k` is bigger than the `len(students_grades)` so it is unlikely to happen .. Thank you for you help <3

Comment: @AhmadEbrahim Oh sorry, I fully expected that inner for loop to be an indentation mistake, but in that case students_grades never contains more than one element (since in the same lowest level for loop you add one element, and remove at least one element). (in fact, that might be the problem: you add one element, and try to remove k elements)